# Issues with mail sending in php

Tags: php, email

So I have been working on a project and I have a function that will send emails out to employees whose employer is chosen.  Now this is working except the mail function (I am using winhost and we need to include Mail.php in order for the mailing function to work) It will sometimes send 3 emails out instead of 2 and sometimes 1 email instead of 2.

The code :

```
if (isset($_POST['openemailmem'])){
    $memberuser = $_POST['openemailmemusername'];
    $sql = "SELECT email, username, password, status FROM csvdata WHERE memberview =:user ";
    $getinfo=$DBH->prepare($sql);
    $getinfo->execute(array(':user' => $memberuser));

    while ($row = $getinfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $check = $row;
        $newEmployeeEmail = $check['email'];
        $csvusername = $check['username'];
        $password = $check['password'];
        $status = $check['status'];

        if ($status == "Open"){
            echo "tesing";
            $from = "the email of where it is coming from is here but i removed";  
            $to = $newEmployeeEmail; 
            if (!empty($_POST['cc'])){
                $cc = $_POST['cc']; 
            }
            if (!empty($_POST['ccsend'])){
                $cc = $_POST['ccsend'];
                $to .= ", $cc";
            }
            $subject = "removed msg"; 
            $body = "removed msg"; 
            $host = "i removed"; 
            $username = "i removed"; 
            $password = "i removed"; 
            $headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to,'Cc' => $cc, 'Subject' => $subject); 
            $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password)); 
            $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
        }       
    }

    header("Location: I removed this.php?getmsg=12");
    exit;

}
```

Thank you for all your time!!!

Comment: Have you checked the data in your DB for those exception cases you hinted at?

Comment: So you get "tesing" appear three times, but only 2 e-mails go (or similar) ? In that case, it's not a problem with the code you've posted, but with either the mail factory or the actual sending. We'll only be guessing from here on.

Comment: Yes I believe it is with the mailing function...any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is most likely in your logs. If exceptions are thrown, you can find them in there.

Additionally a suggestion:

Add logging before and after the loop. So your example becomes:

```
if (isset($_POST['openemailmem']))
{
    $memberuser = $_POST['openemailmemusername'];
    $sql        = "SELECT email, username, password, status "
                . "FROM csvdata WHERE memberview =:user ";
    $getinfo    = $DBH->prepare($sql);
    $getinfo->execute(array(':user' => $memberuser));

    $log_file = "/home/my/transaction.log";
    $now      = "[" . date("Ymd-His") . "] ";

    $message = $now . "Starting loop...";
    error_log($message, 3, $log_file);

    while ($row = $getinfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    {

        $check            = $row;
        $newEmployeeEmail = $check['email'];
        $csvusername      = $check['username'];
        $password         = $check['password'];
        $status           = $check['status'];

        if ($status == "Open")
        {
            echo "tesing";
            $from = "the email of where it is coming from is here but i removed";  
            $to   = $newEmployeeEmail; 
            if (!empty($_POST['cc']))
            {
                $cc = $_POST['cc']; 
            }
            if (!empty($_POST['ccsend']))
            {
                $cc = $_POST['ccsend'];
                $to .= ", $cc";
            }
            $subject  = "removed msg"; 
            $body     = "removed msg"; 
            $host     = "i removed"; 
            $username = "i removed"; 
            $password = "i removed"; 
            $headers = array(
                           'From'    => $from, 
                           'To'      => $to,
                           'Cc'      => $cc, 
                           'Subject' => $subject,
                       );

            $now     = "[" . date("Ymd-His") . "] ";
            $message = $now . "Before connecting to server - " . $to;
            error_log($message, 3, $log_file);

            $smtp = Mail::factory(
                'smtp', 
                 array(
                     'host'     => $host, 
                     'auth'     => true, 
                     'username' => $username, 
                     'password' => $password,
                 )
            ); 

            $now     = "[" . date("Ymd-His") . "] ";
            $message = $now . "After connecting to server - " . $to;
            error_log($message, 3, $log_file);

            $now     = "[" . date("Ymd-His") . "] ";
            $message = $now . "Before sending email - " . $to;
            error_log($message, 3, $log_file);

            $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

            $now     = "[" . date("Ymd-His") . "] ";
            $message = $now . "After sending email - " . $to;
            error_log($message, 3, $log_file);
        }       
    }

    $now     = "[" . date("Ymd-His") . "] ";
    $message = $now . "End of loop";
    error_log($message, 3, $log_file);

    header("Location: I removed this.php?getmsg=12");
   exit;

}
```

You might find that your function times out, depending of how long it takes the mailer to dispatch the email to the relevant host.

From what I see for every user there is a (potentially) unique connection to a mail server and then the email is sent. If for whatever reason there is a delay in establishing that connection then your script could very well time out.

You can adjust the error logging method above to use `microtime` so that you can see the real time between each iteration of your code - of course you will need to add more logging in between blocks of code.

If you find out that it is indeed a delay in the mail server connection etc. you could (if your requirements allow you to) connect once to one server and send your emails from there.

HTH

Comment: Okay so I received this when I echo it - [20120925-170523] End of loop

Comment: So the very last statement (the error_log one) executed but nothing in between? It should at least have the first statement (Starting loop). Don't you see any of that? Also, check that your $memberuser variable is populated properly.

Comment: So before sending the email I get `[20120925-173006] Before sending email - d@gmail.com 0.79420900 1348619406`and after i get `[20120925-173006] After sending email - d@gmail.com0.88693700 1348619406` then it goes through the list of other ones.  but this seems to be a pretty decent delay and I believe this is the issue.  I do not know how to fix this though?

Comment: I did it wrong when I posted that one 2nd to top.  I get everything printed out but I wasnt getting much info so I did micro

Comment: If this is a CLI script i.e. you run it through the command line, then you can let the script run every say 10 minutes and only process X records. When a record is processed then you can update a "sent" flag in the table and with every run you get less and less records. You could also try using one mail server to send your emails out. This way you move the $smtp object outside the loop which would speed things up significantly. If you are afraid that you might be flagged for spam because you send too fast then you can use usleep to slow down the execution.

Comment: Also you can use something max_execution_time (ini_set is the command you need) to something quite high. Finally you can try loading this page once and create some sort of a check at the top of the file. If there are no records exit immediately. If there are records, process some (say 10) and reload yourself. This entails you implement the "sent" flag mentioned in my previous comment. Note that CLI scripts cannot reload themselves. HTH

Comment: Hey I am going to try the $smtp out of the loop first if it does not work I'll keep you posted! Thanks

Comment: Hey so I put the $stmp on the top of the php file and I still seems to not be working.  What else can I do?

Comment: Then your sending server is delaying so much so as to "break" the script (timeout). Other thoughts would be the reloading script that I wrote above (only if you do this from a web interface) or you could offload your mailing to another service that will do these for you. jangosmtp.com could very well be a good solution.

Comment: what is the best way to fix this?

Comment: I would use an external service to send the emails. Send all the data you want to them and let them do the delivery. Easier for you and less strain on your system.

Comment: That I do not know. Most likely it is not. You will have to do some research on that.